# I'm trying to make a POST request to HealthcareFinder API v3.0, but I can not. Returns this error

Tags: healthcare-finder-api

I'm trying to make a POST request to API v3.0, but I can not. Returns this error.

https://api.finder.healthcare.gov/v3.0/getCountiesForZip. Invalid HTTP status code 503

It's about CORS, but e tried all possible ways to request, following and enabling CORS, but nothing works

Comment: If you try the link in the browser, you get this message: The System is down at the moment.

We're working to resolve the issue as soon as possible. Please try again later.

Comment: What are you including in the POST body? Are you including the appropriate Content-Type header?

Comment: Andrew's comment is consistent with the HTTP status code being returned.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you include the `Content-Type` header and the XML for the request in the POST body.

When I try [their example](https://finder.healthcare.gov/#services/version_3_0) it seems to work fine and the HTTP header includes `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` which should work for CORS.

[image: screenshot of RESTClient API call]